# merge two javascripts array objects by adding index based on count

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, salesforce-lightning

I have the following object:

```
index;
@track cashList = [{Id: "",Index: index }];
```

My service outputs below object array:

```
result = [{Id:"100"},{Id:"101"},{Id:"102"}];
```

after merging with the `result`, `cashList` should look like

```
@track cashList = [{Id: "100",Index: 0 },{Id: "101",Index: 1 },{Id: "102",Index: 2 }];

cashList = result; //This one populating `Id` but not sure how to populate index
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `result = [{Id:"100",Id:"101",Id:"102"}];` will only have one property for the single object inside the array: `[{ Id: "102" }]`

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Sorry there was a typo. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can map over an array and pass in the index so in the below `...item` means you are keeping the existing object and adding in the index.

```
result.map((item,index) => ({
    ...item,
    index
}))
```